# How can i make the text in my web server change line

Tags: python, html, flask

Hey i did a small project to display text on a web server but for some reason all the text is on the same line and i don't know how to change it.

code:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def main():
    return """fxfxzvxczxcvxvzx
cxzvxczxcvcxvfdsvxz"""

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, host="127.0.0.1", port=5050)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case you need to pass your output as html format to frontend; `<br>` and `</br>` are linebreaker tags in html;

**Try this:**

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def main():
    template = "fxfxzvxczxcvxvzx</br>cxzvxczxcvcxvfdsvxz"
    return template

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, host="127.0.0.1", port=5050)
```

****Notes:****

if you want to setup and export html format on larger scale you need to do it by **flask template engine render** or designer-friendly templating language like **jinja** just check these three links:

1. https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#rendering-templates
2. https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/tutorial/templates/
3. https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/

Comment: Thank you so much but what if i wanted to do this on a larger scale

Comment: @Jigsaw Updated; check my notes.

Comment: @Jigsaw i appreciate that if you accept the answer.